# Working on edit with nested arrays in result (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a students_record table and i am saving my data in json format there

```
$students_data = Students::findOrFail($id);

     $attributes = DB::table('studentsdata')->where('id', $student_data->id)->select('attributes')->first();
  $result = json_decode($student_data->meta_attributes);
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($result);
            die;
```

I am getting result as

```
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => test
    [status] => Suscess
    [country] => Array
        (
            [0] => Pakistan
            [1] => USA
        )

    [days_time] => months

)
```

I passed result to view and i an getting first name simply as

```
<label> Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
           <div class="input-icon right">
                 <input type="text" name="name" value="{{isset($result->name) ? $result->name : '' }}" />
           </div>
              </div>
```

Its giving my my name in that field fine now

**i want to get countries array also in my country field All countries in that array please Help how can i get it here** which i have in $result as i show input above against my query

```
<label> Country </label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="input-icon right">
                            <select id="country" multiple name="country[]" onchange="
                            getValue('opens-clicks-region', 'student_tracking', 'region', 'country', this.value, this.id)" disabled="disabled">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach loop to generate `<option>` tags, if you are using laravel blade its much easier

```
@foreach ($result->country as $country)
    <option value="{{ $country }}"> {{ $country }} </option>
@endforeach
```

take a look at the blade documentation here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#loops

Comment: i have drop down in this case it should be selected countries how can i achive it

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this

```
<select id="country" multiple name="country[]" onchange="getValue('opens-clicks-region', 'student_tracking', 'region', 'country', this.value, this.id)" disabled="disabled">
    @if(!empty($result->country))
        @foreach($result->country as $key => $country)
            <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $country }}</option>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <!-- Default case if there is no country -->
        <option value="default_key">Default value</option>
    @endif
</select>
```

FYI: Laravel blade has a [check](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#displaying-data) for isset input field

You can replace

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{isset($result->name) ? $result->name : '' }}" />
```

with

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $result->name or '' }}" />
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i have drop down in this case it should be selected countries how can i achive it

Comment: and it says undefined variable $result

Comment: however in my edit its giving result fine as $result->country